# Export a dictionary of dataframes to JSON with Datetime index

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dictionary of dataframes each one with a Datetime Index, as follows:

```
z = {'a': df1, 'b': df2, 'c': df3}

print(df1.head(3))

                   Sales  Pre-tax_Income  ...  Profit_Margin  Gross_Margin
2013-02-28  1.909350e+07   -2.557250e+06  ...      -0.220741     -0.133933
2013-05-31  6.909194e+06   -3.371473e+06  ...      -0.220507     -0.487969
2013-08-31  9.655660e+06    1.447535e+05  ...      -0.126062      0.014992
```

I need to store the data in a JSON file with the following structure:

```
{
    "a": {
       "2013-02-28": { "Sales": 1.909350e+07, ... "Gross Margin": -0.133933},
       "2013-05-31": { "Sales": 6.909194e+06, ... "Gross Margin": -0.487969},
     (...)
    "b": {...}
```

I've tried a piece of code from another post:

```
# convert dataframes into dictionaries
data_dict = {
    key: z[key].to_dict(orient='records')
    for key in z.keys()}

# write to disk
with open('file.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data_dict, fp, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

and what I get is a JSON with the structure I want but without the Index:

```
{
    "a": [
       {"Sales": 1.909350e+07, (...)
        "Gross Margin": -0.133933}
  (...)
 }
```

How can I get a correct JSON file structure and keep my Datetime Index from my dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this

```
data_dict = {
    key: z[key].to_dict(orient='records')
    for key in z.keys()}
```

to this

```
data_dict = {
    key: {k : v for k, v in 
    zip(z[key].index.values, z[key].to_dict(orient='records'))}
    for key in z.keys()}
```

Comment: Does JSON support a Datetime index? Because I'm getting the following error msg: "TypeError: key numpy.datetime64('2013-03-31T00:00:00.000000000') is not a string"

Comment: I have never tried, but I think it will require a conversion with `.strftime("%d/%m/%y")` or something of this nature.

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm. I did:     for key, values in z.items():
        values.index = values.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')